# LINQ to SQL doesnt update a bool field

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following code:

```
using (DataContext dContext = new DataContext())
{
   foreach (long referenceId in referenceIds)
   {
      FriendRefer friendRefer = (from fr in dContext.FriendRefers
                                 where fr.ReferrenceId == referenceId
                                 select fr).Single();

      friendRefer.IsEmailSent = true;
      dContext.SubmitChanges();
   }
}
```

`FriendRefers` table has a bool column called `IsEmailSent`, when a new record is entered this column is set to false, but in the above code I am attempting to change it to true.

I do not see this reflected in the database.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Does your table have a PrimaryKey (or your DataContext)? Linq won't update without one.

Comment: Don't you need to call `SaveChanges();`?

Comment: "New record", so does this mean you are trying to insert a new record and the boolean is set to false? You probably have a primary key violation if it wasn't designed to autogenerate the primary key values.

Comment: Can you show us your **connection string**, please?

Comment: @marc_s Is the connection string really relevant?

Comment: @Alireza: I have a hunch - it *could* be relevant, yes!

Comment: @marc_s May I ask to explain how a connection string or one of its properties is related?

Comment: @Alireza: my hunch is: the OP could be using SQL Server **Express** with the `AttachDbFileName=` property. Doing so will make Visual Studio copy around the `.mdf` file when debugging - to the output directory where the app runs. The insert into *that* copy of the database works - but the OP is then looking at the original `.mdf` somewhere else and can't find his data that was inserted ... seen this a **thousand times** here already...

Comment: The table does have a primary key (ReferenceId), the record already exist in the table, as the code suggests, I am reading the record, update the IsEmailSent filed and submit the changes.

Comment: Do any other properties update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyp gave me the answer, my table did not have primary key set